# How to add value to array after checking another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays as such :

```
UserGroupUser[{Id:"1",UserId:"2",UserGroupId"1"},
           {Id:"2",UserId:"3",UserGroupId"1"},
            {Id:"3",UserId:"4",UserGroupId"2"}]
```

*UserGroupId* will have values such as 1, 2, 3 etc.

```
Employee[{EmployeeId:"1", EmpName:"John", Email:"john@example.com"},
       {EmployeeId:"2", EmpName:"Mary", Email:"Mary@example.com"},
         {EmployeeId:"3", EmpName:"Sarah", Email:"Sarah@example.com"},
         {EmployeeId:"4", EmpName:"Jake", Email:"Jake@example.com"}   ]
```

I will store a number in a variable ***GroupId*** such as GroupId=1
and what i want to do is check the **UserGroupUser** table if GroupId 1 matches any rows for key UserGroupId and if there is a match for every UserId the corresponding EmployeeId in Employee table that matches would mean i add a new element called *enrolled=true.* else if there is not match add a element to Employee *enrolled=false*.

for eg:

If GroupId is =1 then i want to get the userId of those with the UserGroupId as 1 in the UserGroupUser array and add enrolled:true into the Employee array EmployeeId to those corresponding to the UserId .

This is how i tried to do it..

```
 UserGroupUser.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
                    if (arrayItem.UserGroupId === GroupId) {
                        result = Employee.map(function (a, index, array) {
                            while (arrayItem.UserId === a.EmployeeNo) {

                                a.enrolled = true;
                            }

                            return a;
                        }
                        );
                    }
                    else {
                        result = Employee.map(function (a, index, array) {
                            a.enrolled = false;
                            return a;
                        }
                        );

                    }
                });
```

what am i doing wrong? how should i do this?

Comment: you cannot return from `Array.forEach()`

Comment: i think you need to change the array employee by adding enrolled = true/false isnt it

Comment: The return is from the map() function which will assign the new changed Employee array to result.

Comment: yes... if that user is in the UserGroupUser array under GroupId = 1

Comment: Okay 1 min let me create the fiddle

Comment: Why use a while loop at all?

Comment: 'while (arrayItem.UserId === a.EmployeeNo) {' but your 'Employee' array doesn't have the key 'EmployeeNo'

Comment: sorry typo .. it should be EmployeeNo in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var userGroup = [{Id:"1",UserId:"2",UserGroupId:"1"},
           {Id:"2",UserId:"3",UserGroupId:"1"},
            {Id:"3",UserId:"4",UserGroupId:"2"}]

var employees = [{EmployeeId:"1", EmpName:"John", Email:"john@example.com"},
       {EmployeeId:"2", EmpName:"Mary", Email:"Mary@example.com"},
         {EmployeeId:"3", EmpName:"Sarah", Email:"Sarah@example.com"},
         {EmployeeId:"4", EmpName:"Jake", Email:"Jake@example.com"}   ]

employees.forEach(function(item){
        var found = userGroup.filter(i=>i.UserId==item.Id);
        if(found.length>0)
            item.enrolled = true
        else
            item.enrolled = false
})

console.log(employees);
```

the employees then will contained the enrolled or not try this in your console too

Comment: I will be getting a value to a variable GroupId. This i must match with userGroup.UserGroupId and then do the changes to only those users under that group

Comment: i havnt seen group id in employees list can you add them Then i will update the answre

Comment: there isnt. Basically I want to change enrolled : true in employee table on those employees that are in *groupId =1* in the userGroup table...

Comment: so how to know which employee is in groud Id =1 without a property in employee list. ie i need to check with some value.

Comment: Basically, a employee from the employee table will be added to a group. Then they will be added to the UserGroup table with their employeeNo as UserId and to which group they belong.. i.e groupId=1. Then i would go about searching for all the users under a specicfic groupId and changed those users in the employee table with enrolled : true . when i say specific group id this is given as a argument .. so it can change..

Comment: Can you please create any fiddle or somthing with your array. So that I can help edit them.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lccd2fpf/ 

so if the users exist in group 1 then they should be checked. (enrolled:true)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that when `if (arrayItem.UserGroupId === GroupId) {` is executed, it changes `enrolled` to `true` for the concerned employees but when the `else` part of this check is executed, it overrides the changes made by the `if` condition part.
Try this.

```
UserGroupUser = [{Id:"1",UserId:"2",UserGroupId:"1"},
             {Id:"2",UserId:"3",UserGroupId:"1"},
             {Id:"3",UserId:"4",UserGroupId:"2"}];
Employee = [{EmployeeId:"1", EmpName:"John", Email:"john@example.com"},
        {EmployeeId:"2", EmpName:"Mary", Email:"Mary@example.com"},
        {EmployeeId:"3", EmpName:"Sarah", Email:"Sarah@example.com"},
        {EmployeeId:"4", EmpName:"Jake", Email:"Jake@example.com"}];
GroupId = "1";
Employee.map(function (emp) {
  emp.enrolled = false;
});
UserGroupUser.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
  if (arrayItem.UserGroupId === GroupId) {
    Employee.map(function (emp) {
      if (arrayItem.UserId === emp.EmployeeId) {
        emp.enrolled = true;
      }
    });
  }
});
console.log(Employee);
```